# Letter combinations in two subsets of a set of size n

Tags: combinatorics

We have a set of n-element letters.  The letters in the set can be repeated. How much is the possibility of creating two subsets, so that the combinations of subsets will not be repeated? Example1: a set consists of 5 elements {a,a,b,b,c}.  The possible combinations are:

```
{a}, {a,b,b,c}
{b},{a,a,b,c}
{c},{a,a,b,b}
{a,a} ,{b,b,c}
{a,b},{a,b,c}
{a,c},{a,a,b}
{b,b},{a,a,c}
{b,c},{a,a,b}
```

So the answer is 8. Example2:a set consists of 3 elements {a,b,b}.  The possible combinations are:

```
{a},{b,b}
{a,b},{b}
```

So the answer is 2. Example3:a set consists of 3 elements {a,b,c}.  The possible combinations are:

```
{a},{b,c}
{a,b},{c}
{a,c},{b}
```

So the answer is 3. Is there a formula for n elements and k repetitions of letters in the set? Thank You.

Comment: Side-note: When elements may repeat, the correct terminology is *multi-set*.

Comment: What do you mean by "creating two subsets, so that the letters will not be repeated"? Of the eight "possible combinations" there is only one in which both subsets are free of repetition, and if there were three copies of any letter there would be no such combination at all. How do you count $7$ possibilities in this example?

Comment: I gave another two examples to illustrate what I mean.. but I think I gave the wrong name for my problem, first time when i wrote my post. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by barak manos, a set where elements may repeat is a multi-set.

Let's say that in the multi-set $M$ there are $k_1$ occurrences of symbol $a_1$; ...; $k_n$ occurrences of symbol $a_n$.

Step 1: Count all sub-multi-sets of $M$.  There are $k_1+1$ choices for how many times $a_1$ occurs in our sub-multi-set (since $0$ up to $k_1$ are all possibilities); similarly for $a_2, ..., a_k$.  So there are $(k_1+1)\cdot (k_2+1)\cdots (k_n+1)$ sub-multi-sets of $M$.

Step 2: Count $2$-set partitions of $M$.  Each sub-multi-set in step 1, and its complement form a two-set partition, except that we exclude the pair $\{\emptyset,M\}$ since the subsets of a partition must be nonempty.  Also in the case that all $k_i$ are even, then there is one sub-multi-set that is self-complementary (note also that in this case the total number of sub-multi-sets in step 1 will be odd).

So we have a total of $\lceil \frac{(k_1+1)\cdot (k_2+1)\cdots (k_n+1)-2}{2}\rceil$ partitions.  (The outer delimiters are the ceiling function; the subtracted $2$ in the numerator gets rid of the sub-multi-sets $\emptyset$ and $M$; and the ceiling function takes care of the case where there is one self-complementary sub-multi-set.)

In the example provided in the original problem, the $k$-values are $2,2,1$.  So the above gives $\lceil\frac{3\cdot 3\cdot 2-2}{2}\rceil=8$ (which matches the list given by OP, although the number is then miscounted/misreported as $7$ in OP's post).

Comment: Of course 8 not 7 you're right. I made a small mistake in counting answers :D